# Crossbar is throwing AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'make_batched_timer'

Tags: python, autobahn, crossbar

When I try to run crossbar getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    from crossbar.controller.cli import run
  File "/Users/mahesh/.virtualenvs/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/crossbar/controller/cli.py", line 49, in <module>
    from autobahn.twisted.choosereactor import install_reactor
  File "/Users/mahesh/.virtualenvs/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autobahn/twisted/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from autobahn.twisted.websocket import \
  File "/Users/mahesh/.virtualenvs/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autobahn/twisted/websocket.py", line 42, in <module>
    from autobahn.wamp import websocket
  File "/Users/mahesh/.virtualenvs/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autobahn/wamp/websocket.py", line 31, in <module>
    from autobahn.websocket import protocol
  File "/Users/mahesh/.virtualenvs/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autobahn/websocket/protocol.py", line 362, in <module>
    class WebSocketProtocol(object):
  File "/Users/mahesh/.virtualenvs/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autobahn/websocket/protocol.py", line 550, in WebSocketProtocol
    _batched_timer = txaio.make_batched_timer(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'make_batched_timer'
```

Crossbar version : 0.15.0

python version : 2.7.10

Operating System : OSX 10.11.6

Comment: Do you have a local file named `txaio.py` perhaps? What does adding in the line `import txaio; print txaio` before the `from crossbar.controller.cli import run` produce?

Comment: Its prints `<module 'txaio' from 'txaio/__init__.pyc'>`

Comment: Looks like your `txaio` package might be too old. That method was added in [version 2.4.0](https://github.com/crossbario/txaio/commit/8ca1d5791cf652c8f599f3d77bc141a874d24d93).

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters It worked. The issue is with the version.